# How to show timeline in matplotlib.axes.Axes.stem plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am doing a `matplotlib.axes.Axes.stem` graph where the x-axis is a dateline that shows days. Some of my data appear on certain days. While on other days, it has no data (because such info do not exist in my data).

**Question 1:** How do I make a timeline stem graph that will show my data, including days with no data? Is this possible? Is there some way to auto-scale the appearance of the data x-axis to handle such a situation?

Below is a sample data file called `test.txt` and my python script to read in its data to show a timeline stem plot for your consideration. output from this script is also given below.

**Question2.** Presentation question. How do I show a "-" symbol at each annotation? Also, how do I rotate the annotation by 30 degrees?

**test.txt**

```
No. Date 
1   23/01/2020
2   24/01/2020
3   24/01/2020
4   26/01/2020
5   27/01/2020
6   28/01/2020
7   29/01/2020
8   29/01/2020
9   30/01/2020
10  30/01/2020
11  31/01/2020
12  31/01/2020
13  01/02/2020
14  01/02/2020
15  04/02/2020
16  04/02/2020
17  04/02/2020
18  05/02/2020
19  05/02/2020
20  05/02/2020
21  06/02/2020
22  07/02/2020
23  07/02/2020
24  07/02/2020
25  08/02/2020
26  08/02/2020
27  08/02/2020
28  08/02/2020
29  08/02/2020
30  09/02/2020
31  10/02/2020
32  10/02/2020
33  11/02/2020
34  11/02/2020
38  13/02/2020
39  13/02/2020
40  13/02/2020
41  13/02/2020
42  13/02/2020
43  13/02/2020
44  14/02/2020
45  14/02/2020
46  14/02/2020
47  14/02/2020
48  14/02/2020
49  14/02/2020
50  15/02/2020
51  15/02/2020
52  15/02/2020
53  15/02/2020
54  15/02/2020
57  18/02/2020
58  18/02/2020
59  18/02/2020
60  19/02/2020
61  21/02/2020
```

**stem_plot.py**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime

from pathlib import Path

#########################
#### DATA EXTRACTION ####
#########################
source = Path('./test.txt')
with source.open() as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
#print( lines )

# Store source data in dictionary with date shown as mm-dd. 
data={}
for line in lines[1:]:
    case, cdate = line.strip().split()
    cdate = datetime.strptime(cdate, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime('%m-%d')
    data[case] = cdate
print( f'\ndata = {data}' )

# Collate data's y-axis for each date, i.e. history
history2={}
cdates = list(data.values())
sorted_dates = sorted( set( cdates ) )
for i in sorted_dates:
    cases=[]
    for case, date in data.items():
        if i == date:
            cases.append(case)
    #print( i, cases)
    history2[i] = cases 
print( f'\nhistory2 = {history2}')

###########################
#### DATA PRESENTATION ####
###########################
# Create figure and plot a stem plot with the date
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8.8, 5), constrained_layout=True)
ax.set(title="Test")

labels=list( history2.values() ) # For annotation 
yy = [ len(i) for i in labels ]  # y-axis
xx = list(history2.keys())       # x-axis
markerline, stemline, baseline = ax.stem(
    xx, yy, linefmt="C1:", basefmt="k-", use_line_collection=True)

plt.setp(markerline, marker="None" ) 

# annotate stem lines
for ann_x, label in list(history2.items()):
    print(ann_x, label)
    each_count=1
    for each in label:
        ax.annotate( each, xy=(ann_x, each_count), xycoords='data')
        each_count += 1
        #print(f'each_count = {each_count}' )

# format xaxis
plt.setp( ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30 )

# remove top and right spines
for spine in ["top", "right"]:
    ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)

# show axis name
ax.get_yaxis().set_label_text(label='Y-axis')
ax.get_xaxis().set_label_text(label='X-axis')

plt.show()
```

**Current output:**

[image: test.png]

Comment: Could you post the code you have so far? (Also, an image of the output.)

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I have provided those info that you had asked.

Comment: Do you have to use a text file and plot using a dictionary? Would it be OK to use something like pandas?

Comment: @SinanKurmus Sure. More importantly, I need advice on the matplotlib part. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your first question. Basically, you make a list of all days between the days you are using and use that. So add this to the beginning of your code:

```
import pandas as pd
alldays = pd.date_range(start="20200123", 
                     end="20200221", 
                     normalize=True)
dates = []
for i in alldays:
    dates.append(f"{i.month:02}-{i.day:02}")
```

What this does is it gets a pandas data range between two dates and converts this range into a list of month-day strings.

Then modify this part of your code like this:

```
# Collate data's y-axis for each date, i.e. history
history2={}
cdates = list(data.values())
sorted_dates = sorted( set( cdates ) )
for i in dates:  # This is the only change!
    cases=[]
    for case, date in data.items():
        if i == date:
            cases.append(case)
    #print( i, cases)
    history2[i] = cases
```

And this change would give you this:

[image: Stem Plot 1]

About your second question, change your code to this:

```
# annotate stem lines
for ann_x, label in list(history2.items()):
    print(ann_x, label)
    each_count=1
    for each in label:
        ax.annotate(f"--{each}", xy=(ann_x, each_count), xycoords='data', rotation=30)
        each_count += 1
```

I just changed the `ax.annotate` line. The two changes are:

1. added a "--" to each of your annotation labels,
2. added a rotation parameter. The rotation parameter does not appear directly in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html), but the documentation says you can use any of the methods for Text as `kwargs`, and they are [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text).

This would hopefully give you what you have asked for:

[image: Stem Plot 2]

Answer (score 0):

**Adding to @SinanKurmus answer to my 1st Question:**

## Solution1:

A time-axis with a daily interval for the entire history of the given data can be obtained using matplotlib's methods, namely [drange](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/dates_api.html?highlight=drange#matplotlib.dates.drange) and [num2date](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/dates_api.html?highlight=drange#matplotlib.dates.num2date), and python. The use of pandas can be avoided here.

First, express the start and end date of the time axis as a python datetime object. Note, you need to add 1 more day to the end date else data from the last date would not be included. Next, use 1 day as your time interval using python's `datetime.timedelta` object. Next supply them to `matplotlib.date.drange` method that will return a NumPy array. Matplotlib's num2date method in turns converts that back to a python datetime object.

```
def get_time_axis( data ):
    start = datetime.strptime(min(data.values()), "%Y-%m-%d")
    end = datetime.strptime(max(data.values()), "%Y-%m-%d") + timedelta(days=1)
    delta = timedelta(days=1)
    time_axis_md = mdates.drange( start, end, delta )
    time_axis_py = mdates.num2date( time_axis_md, tz=None ) # Add tz when required
    return time_axis_py
```

## Solution 2:

Apparently, Matplotlib also has a FAQ on [how to skip dates where there is no data](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/faq/howto_faq.html?highlight=faq%20date#skip-dates-where-there-is-no-data). I have included their sample code example below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

r = mlab.csv2rec('../data/aapl.csv')
r.sort()
r = r[-30:]  # get the last 30 days

N = len(r)
ind = np.arange(N)  # the evenly spaced plot indices

def format_date(x, pos=None):
    thisind = np.clip(int(x+0.5), 0, N-1)
    return r.date[thisind].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(ind, r.adj_close, 'o-')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```